# How to resolve a double reference for the displayed choice text in a SelectInput field in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin, react-final-form

I have basically three lists:

- `Locations` with fields `lid` and `lname`
- `Mapping` with fields `locationId` and `someOtherListId`
- the Main list where to store the selected mappings

I want the user to be able to select mappings from the mappings table with the location names displayed. So I need to resolve a reference to `Mapping` where the `locationId` field contains a reference to `Locations` where I want to show the `lname` field als choices.

I tried with the code below, but it gives me a 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` which occurs in the `<ReferenceField/>`.

```
<ArrayInput source="mappings" >
   <SimpleFormIterator>
      <ReferenceInput
          label="Select mapping"
          source="mappingId"
          reference="Mapping">
         <SelectInput optionText={
            <ReferenceField source="locationId" reference="locations">
              <TextField source="lname"/>
            </ReferenceField>
         } />
      </ReferenceInput>
   </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

So obviously it is not possible to use a `<ReferenceField/>` in the `OptionText` function.

What can I try instead?